# Ubuntu 20.04 losing network connection every night at some point after midnight

Tags: networking, server

I still consider myself a Linux noob. I have a Lenovo M710q running 20.04. As far as I can tell, the machine is running just fine. It has a wired connection. I'm using it as a Plex server. Every single night, at some point between 12:00 a.m. and when I get back to my desk (usually around 7/8 a.m.) it loses connection to the network and won't reestablish it until I reboot the device, then it connects automatically. I specify network because I can't even access it via RDP anymore. I'm not sure what to do to even begin troubleshooting this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: You're sure  it isn't the network?

Comment: Is there a setting in your router which removes access between certain times? router manger 192.168.1.1 usually.

Comment: Yes, that is default in many routers to renew IP address. Also, some ISPs will force that.

Comment: @waltinator hello! I ran `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager` and I didn't see ANY lines that show `man journalctl`.

Comment: @NathanToulbert Hello, and yes I'm 90% sure it isn't the network. I have several computers that are on 24/7 and only this machine has issues. I have all of my network devices granted static IPs so I don't think it's an IP renewal issue. I configured the IPs on the router end.

Comment: Try setting it somewhere in the 240s. The DNHS usually starts from the bottom and works it's way up. Unless it is a reused router provided by the ISP company, it should never get anywhere near that end... Remember that there is at least one dnhs server built into Ubuntu; You could always let it assign the ips itself... it's a great way to test your theory.

Comment: One more thing; for your devices that are further away, switch to the 5.0 signal, if you have one. They arent as fast as the 2.4, but they will carry alot further without cutting out.